# Cross apply historical date range in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a growing table of orders which looks something like this:

| units_sold | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-02 10:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-03-02 11:00:00 |
| 4 | 2021-03-02 12:00:00 |
| 3 | 2021-03-03 13:00:00 |
| 9 | 2021-03-03 14:00:00 |

I am trying to partition the table into each day, and gather statistics on units sold on the day, and on the day before. I can pretty easily get the units sold today and yesterday for just today, but I need to cross apply a date range for every date in my orders table.

The expected result would look like this:

| units_sold_yesterday | units_sold_today | date_measured |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 7 | 2021-03-02 |
| NULL | 12 | 2021-03-03 |

One way of doing it, is by creating or appending the order data every day to a new table. However, this table could grow very large and also I need historical data as well.

In my minds eye I know I have cascade the data, so that BigQuery compares the data to "todays date" which would shift across a all the dates in the table.

I'm thinking this shift could come from a cross apply of all the distinct dates in the table, and so I would get a copy of the orders table for each date, but with a different "todays date" column that I can extrapolate the `units_sold_today` data from by using that column to date-diff the salesdate to.

This would still, however, create a massive amount of data to process, and I guess maybe there is a simple function for this in BigQuery or standard SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like aggregation and `lag()`:

```
select timestamp_trunc(timestamp, day), count(*) as sold_today,
       lag(count(*)) over (order by min(timestamp)) as sold_yesterday
from t
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Note:  This assumes that you have data for every day.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select date_measured, units_sold_today,
  lag(units_sold_today) over(order by date_measured) units_sold_yesterday,
from (
  select date(timestamp) date_measured,
    sum(units_sold) units_sold_today
  from `project.dataset.table` 
  group by date_measured
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]